# JNDI name weblogic.management.server is not available in WebLogic 12.2.1.3

Tags: weblogic12c

In one of our java code we are performing a look up in **WebLogic 12.2.1.3** version.
`ctx.lookup("weblogic.management.server");`

Apparently we received an exception `NamingNotFoundException` due to the JNDI name is not available in WebLogic 12.2.1.3 version , where as it is available in 12.1.3.

We also tried using foreign JNDI name feature but it doesn't resolve the problem.

Could you please provide us any suggestions or alternatives on this?

Answer (score 0):

The MBean interface has been removed on WebLogic 12.2.1, then, this jndi context is no longer available. You should review your code and use another way to get your connection to the jmx server.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Could you please provide any documentation or any links that has code snippets to achieve this in webLogic 12.2.1.

Comment: You can start reading this [documentaton](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/JMXCU/accesswls.htm#JMXCU144).